# Abrir app android via php

Tags: php, javascript, html, android, aplicação-web

Eu tenho um sistema web e gostaria de chamar/abrir um app android instalado em um tablet através de um botão no meu sistema. É possível via php, javascript ou html?

Obrigado,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é possível fazer com qualquer link. O que importa é se o aplicativo tem o intent configurado no manifesto do Activity.

Vamos imaginar que o manifesto do aplicativo esteja assim:

```
<activity>
<!-- ... -->

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="meuapp.com" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Se o aplicativo estiver instalado no aparelho, basta você ter em seu HTML um link como `<a href="https://meuapp.com/">Abrir App</a>` que o aplicativo irá capturar e será aberto automaticamente.

[edit]

Se você não desenvolveu o aplicativo, você deve ter o .apk dele.

Copie o APK instalado do seu dispositivo móvel para um PC que tenha o [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) mais recente instalado.

O Android Studio vem com uma aplicação chamada APK Analyzer que permite você analise o que está dentro do APK e, ainda por cima, ele reconstrói o manifesto de forma que dá para você lê-lo.

Veja aqui um exemplo: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer#view_the_androidmanifestxml

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu quero chamar um app de terceiro via meu sistema, seria desde mesmo modo? Grato